# Activation of iMessage and FaceTime fails (error during activation)

Tags: iphone, messages, apple-id, facetime

Trying to activate iMessage and FaceTime on my MBP (Retina, 13-inch, Early 2015; macOS 10.13.3) keeps returning "An error occurred during activation. Try again."

- I have gone through the suggestions on [this page](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201422), i.e. turning
  them both off, restarting my phone (model A1586, iPhone 6) and
  activating them again, but to no avail.
- I have also made sure that time zone is automatically set in Date &
  Time (both on my iPhone and on my mac).
- I have reset NVRAM.
- I have also ensured that I am actually able to log in to my Apple account online, which works fine.
- I have signed out and in iCloud from both phone and MBP.
- I have checked that location services is on on my iPhone (have even reset location and privacy settings) and on my computer.
- I have checked that my computer's Firewall is Off.
- I have reset all my phone settings.
- I have rebooted into Safe Mode on the computer.
- I get a similar error when I try to make a new user on my mac and log in to Apple Account.
- I have created a new Apple ID, which does not work either.

(Where appropriate, I have after each of these steps restarted both phone and computer.)

Does anyone have any other suggestions on what I can try?

Comment: Check that Location Services is ON or Try disabling Firewall.

Comment: @PratikaRana, thanks for the suggestions. Have now tried both of those, but still without luck...