# Error: Failed entitlement check 'com.apple.private.secure-apsclient'

Tags: facetime, console

Trying to solve [this issue](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/313842/activation-of-imessage-and-facetime-fails-error-during-activation) I have looked in the Console app to further troubleshoot. Here I find the errors:

```
Failed entitlement check 'com.apple.private.secure-apsclient' for <private>

Failed entitlement check 'com.apple.private.aps-connection-initiate' for <private>
```

Can anyone help me understanding what these are and how I might be able to fix them?